# Erasing Python download

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to use the TensorFlow image classifier but halfway through the download my internet connection got lost and I could not download the file.

I understand that I have to delete the partial download and run again to make this work but I am not sure where the file is or how to find it.

I tried searching for the file name "Inception-2015-12-05.tgz" and nothing showed up. My guess is that there is a temporary file name when I downloaded it.

```
  File "classify_image.py", line 227, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "classify_image.py", line 190, in main
    maybe_download_and_extract()
  File "classify_image.py", line 186, in maybe_download_and_extract
    tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(dest_directory)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2007, in extractall
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2049, in extract
    numeric_owner=numeric_owner)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2119, in _extract_member
    self.makefile(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 2168, in makefile
    copyfileobj(source, target, tarinfo.size, ReadError, bufsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tarfile.py", line 248, in copyfileobj
    buf = src.read(bufsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 276, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/gzip.py", line 482, in read
    raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `/tmp/imagenet` folder, then restart the download.